# Google map Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded main.js.27

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map where I can draw polygon. It have been working well all this while and now suddenly I end up with error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded main.js.27. Below is part of my initialise function which I call upon loading the map.Now the moment I complete draw the polyon this error come out.

```
    function clearSelection() {
        for (var n = 0; n<shapes.length; n++) {
            var shapesOne = shapes[n];
            shapesOne.setMap(null);
        }
    }

    function setSelection(shape) {
        selectedShape = shape;
        shape.setEditable(true);
        selectColor(shape.get('fillColor') || shape.get('strokeColor'));
    }

    function deleteSelectedShape() {
        if (selectedShape) {
            selectedShape.setMap(null);
        }
    }

    function selectColor(color) {
        selectedColor = color;
        var polylineOptions = drawingManager.get('polylineOptions');
        polylineOptions.strokeColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('polylineOptions', polylineOptions);

        var rectangleOptions = drawingManager.get('rectangleOptions');
        rectangleOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('rectangleOptions', rectangleOptions);

        var circleOptions = drawingManager.get('circleOptions');
        circleOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('circleOptions', circleOptions);

        var polygonOptions = drawingManager.get('polygonOptions');
        polygonOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('polygonOptions', polygonOptions);
    }

    function setSelectedShapeColor(color) {
        if (selectedShape) {
            if (selectedShape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
                selectedShape.set('strokeColor', color);
            } else {
                selectedShape.set('fillColor', color);
            }
        }
     }

     function makeColorButton(color) {
         var button = document.createElement('span');
         button.className = 'color-button';
         button.style.backgroundColor = color;
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function(){
              selectColor(color);
              setSelectedShapeColor(color);
         });

         return button;
     }

     function buildColorPalette() {
         selectColor("#1E90FF");
     }

     function initialize() {
         geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             zoom: 7,
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.8, 102.5),
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
             mapTypeControl: true,
                 mapTypeControlOptions: {
                      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                    },
             disableDefaultUI: true,
             zoomControl: true
         });


         var contents = document.createElement("div");
         contents.style.width="300px";
         contents.style.height="10px";
         contents.innerHTML="<form name='form2' id='form2' onsubmit='javascript:codeAddress();return false;'><div id='auto' style='z-index:5; position:relative'><input type='text' style='font-family:verdana;width:200px; height:15px;font-size:10px' id='address' name='address' autocomplete='on'  /><input type=\"button\" onclick=\"codeAddress()\" value=\"Search\"/><\/div></form>";


    document.getElementById('map').appendChild(contents);
    document.getElementById("auto").style.top="35px";
    document.getElementById("auto").style.left="35px";
    var polyOptions = {
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillOpacity: 0.45,
        editable: true
    };

    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        markerOptions: {
            draggable: true
        },
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,
                drawingModes: [
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
                ]
        },
        polylineOptions: {
            editable: true
        },
        rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
        circleOptions: polyOptions,
        polygonOptions: polyOptions,
        map: map
    });

   google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
       if(e.type.toString()=="polygon"){
           var points = e.overlay.getPath();
           geoFenceString = "POLYGON((";
           var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
           for (var i =0; i < points.length; i++) {
               var xy = points.getAt(i);
               latlngbounds.extend(xy); 
               geoFenceString = geoFenceString+xy.lng()+" "+xy.lat()+",";                         
           }
           geoFenceString = geoFenceString+points.getAt(0).lng()+" "+points.getAt(0).lat();     
           geoFenceString = geoFenceString+"))";
           var htmlString = '<table idth="100%">\r\n';
           htmlString += '<tr><td>Name</td><td valign="top"><input id="geoFenceName" type="text" style="width:100%" value=""></td></tr>\r\n';
            htmlString += '</tr>\r\n';
            htmlString += '</table>\r\n';
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            });

     }
     });
         google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);

                buildColorPalette();        

        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: @All I found the bug is here drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null); when I off this then the error goes off any idea?

Comment: The posted code contains syntax errors.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rv86o3ae/)

Comment: @geocodezip yes its just part of the codes and now when I comment this line //drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null); the error goes off? Any reason for this ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok I will add more details to my codes shortly

Comment: Ok I have added more codes and tried on the fiddle it still does not work and I ensure no syntax error. Infact I found the cause of the Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded main.js.27 that is this line drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

Comment: Your code is a mess to try and read. Try to format it so its more legible if you want people to try to read it. Also I cannot find the line that you say is causing the error.

Comment: Sorry for my codes. I try to indent when I put at codes in it becomes like this. Anyway I accidently remove the line where the bug is here google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);  if i remove the drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null); then I dont get any error

Comment: @geocodezip its definitely a bug in here so I hope you can remove the downvote to my question as I was the first one pointing it out where the issue is.

Comment: You still have a javascript error in the posted code `Uncaught ReferenceError: shapes is not defined`  when you click on the polygon tool. (because "shapes" is not defined). [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rv86o3ae/2/).  The issue seems to be that calling `drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null)` triggers an `overlaycomplete` event, creating an infinite loop.  See the second answer in the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046582/drawingmanager-setdrawingmodenull-causing-too-much-recursion)

Comment: @geocodesizp I have tried the second answer in my scenario it does not work either. I even tried this google.maps.event.clearListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete');  drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null); it gives me undefined function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else posted a similar question and they suggest this:

```
if (drawManager.getDrawingMode()) {
  drawManager.setDrawingMode(null);
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046582/drawingmanager-setdrawingmodenull-causing-too-much-recursion) to get their full explanation.

Comment: Nope katie I tried ready its not the answer it points to the same problem.  I pretty sure its a bug and I feel bad my question is being put to off when I manage to catch the bug itself.

Comment: I even tried this google.maps.event.clearListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete');
             // drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null); it gives me undefined function

Comment: I'm also getting this error now. Seems to happen only with `Polygon` overlays not `Rectangles`.

Comment: Yes I think many people now coming to realise its a bug I guess maybe something was updated and left to create this bug.

Comment: This works: `google.maps.event.clearListeners(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete'); drawManager.setDrawingMode(null);`

Comment: Ya darwin this works in my case I pop-up and give option to the user to redraw again so what is your suggestion to allow it to have the drawingMode again with the listener

Comment: Yeah - I just ran into that problem myself. Is it possible this bug just surfaced and Google will fix shortly?

Comment: I dont know how to forward this to google looks like many people are going to effected but guess we were the first ones to realise this issue.

Comment: Seems like it is only an issue in 3.exp. I switched back to 3.8 and it's fine. I guess that's what you get for using the bleeding edge.

Comment: I dont know what version I am using cause how to set it ?

Comment: Yes you are right I set it to be ?v=3.8 it works

Comment: The problem still exits on 3.exp. 3.8 works.

Comment: Here is a work-around if you need to use 3.exp, which may be better code anyway. http://dpaste.com/1NNHD98