# drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null) causing too much recursion

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Please check out this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/HoffZ/Zu55b/

Why it is causing error "too much recursion" on `drawMan.setDrawingMode(null)`

```
drawMan.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON);

google.maps.event.addListener(drawMan, 'overlaycomplete', function (event) {
    // When draw mode is set to null you can edit the polygon you just drawed
    drawMan.setDrawingMode(null);
});
```

This is not my fiddle but I am having this exact issue in my code

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7548

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I must admit that I don't quite understand why this happens.

But the following code seems to work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawMan, 'overlaycomplete', function (event) {

    if (drawMan.getDrawingMode()) {

        drawMan.setDrawingMode(null);
    }        
});
```

Comment: Smells google-bug. It happens on 'overlaycomplete' for a Polygon, but not for a Rectangle.

Comment: Good catch. Might be a bug then.

Comment: Have in mind that drawMan.setDrawingMode(null); will trigger overlaycomplete, polygoncomplete 2nd time.

Comment: Well... yes and no. `drawMan.setDrawingMode(null)` alone does not trigger the `overlaycomplete` event. But even `drawMan.getDrawingMode()` when inside the event listener will trigger it. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug. The `setDrawingMode` function seems to be triggering the `overlaycomplete` listener. Only started happening to me today.

MrUpsidown's answer actually triggers `overlaycomplete` a second time. Unless you need to keep listening for the event, you should clear it.

```
drawMan.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON);

google.maps.event.addListener(drawMan, 'overlaycomplete', function (event) {
    google.maps.event.clearListener(drawMan, 'overlaycomplete');
    drawMan.setDrawingMode(null);
});
```

Comment: It does, but only when inside the `overlaycomplete` event listener.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with 3.exp. For now switch it to 3.8  and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

this code works for me, but this is google bug.

```js
if (drawManager.drawingMode) {
  drawManager.setDrawingMode(null);
}
```